# Importing expo-pixi crashes iOS device

Tags: react-native, expo, pixi.js

I have an expo react native project, and I'm trying to capture e-signatures. After installing `expo-pixi`, importing it crashes the device with no warnings. Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure you've done it in this order.

`expo init yourproject` => `cd yourproject` => `yarn add expo-pixi` => `expo start`

and Usage:

```js
import { PIXI } from 'expo-pixi';
...
const app = new PIXI.Application({ context });

const sprite = await PIXI.Sprite.fromExpoAsync('http://i.imgur.com/uwrbErh.png');

// OR 

const texture = await PIXI.Texture.fromExpoAsync('http://i.imgur.com/uwrbErh.png');

const sprite = await PIXI.Sprite.from(require('./icon.png'));
const texture = await PIXI.Texture.from(require('./icon.png'));
```

[documents on a module](https://github.com/expo/expo-pixi)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it is related to that open issue:
https://github.com/expo/expo-pixi/issues/77

Feel free to use the suggested resolution. There is also an open PR attempting to solve that issue, however, maintainer seems to be unreachable which is why this has not been merged yet.

Hopefully this is solving your issue (as I am having the same issue).